# How to configure mDNSResponder to forward requests to the system's DNS server

Tags: network, dns

I've enabled internet sharing from WiFi to USB Ethernet adapter. It starts a DHCP server that creates subnet `192.168.2.0` with host ip `192.168.2.1` and distributes gateway address `192.168.2.1` and DNS address `192.168.2.1` to the Ethernet clients.

The subnet of the WiFi connection is `192.168.0.0` and the gateway and DNS address assigned by it are `192.168.0.1`.

How to make `mDNSResponder` to forward DNS requests to the system's DNS address(`192.168.0.1`).

Comment: If using Internet Sharing, you should not need to do this. Are computers behind the Mac not resolving hostnames?

Comment: @Allan yes. I had to set dns server manually on the computers behind the Mac.

Comment: @Allan, now again I've set the computer behind the Mac to get DNS automatically and now it is working. in the morning it didn't work! when I face this should I've to restart mDNSResponder?

Comment: Just restar Internet Sharing.  How did you set the DNS on the Mac?

Comment: @Allan, it gets automatically from WiFi router